# Elastic Search calculate the difference of two set

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new on Elastic Search. I really need the result about calculating the difference of two set.
Here is the mapping of a index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Date":    { "type": "date", "format": "yyyyMMdd"},  
      "areaID":  { "type": "keyword"  }, 
      "deviceID":   { "type": "keyword"  }
    }
  }
}
```

The date range is from October to November.
I want to get a response for counting November's all new distinct 'deviceID' which grouped by 'areaID'.
I have no idea about how to implement it in ES syntax. Any ES master could give me some hints?
THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You can using aggs of elasticseach to group by `areaID`.
This is example with kibana

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 1000000, 
  "query": {
      "range": {
        "Date": {
          "gte": "2020-10-01",
          "lte": "2020-11-31
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "area_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "areaID.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Date": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "Date",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "2020-11-01",
                "to": "2020-11-31"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "device_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "deviceID.keyword",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is only November data.   But what I need is drop the deviceID which appeared in  October.  Thank you all the same.

Comment: oh i see, I have it updated, I hope it's right

Comment: Thank you again man.   However, I think the result is just same as the one before you updated.   It seems the deviceID in the result is not only exist in November.   BTW, your full name is Ngoc Trung Duc?  And did you got your master degree in Marshall?

Comment: My full name is Nguyen Trung Duc, and this is the first time I hear about the university

Comment: Ok. I thought I meet my classmate, Ha.  Any other idea about this problem? I got stuck for 2 days.....